# Multiply 3D array with vectors in all three dimensions in Python

Tags: python, arrays, vector

I am trying to multiply 3D array `f` by vectors `x`, `y` and `z` in all three dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

f = np.ones((2, 3, 4))

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 2)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 3)
z = np.linspace(0, 10, 4)

print(z * f)
print(y[:, None] * f)
print((x * f.T).T)
```

Is there another way to achieve the last line without having to transpose `f` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you are asking about [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). If so, then reshaping `x` solves the problem:

```
f * x[:,None,None]
f * x.reshape(-1, 1, 1)
```

All we do here is alinging 1-dimentional vector with the dimension of the matrix `f` we are interested in (the same, as you do with `y[:, None] * f`).